# Don't pay the ferryman, until ... future perfect?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, grammar-choice, future-tense

Recently I read that Charon was a *portitor*, i.e., a ferryman. This got me thinking about the phrase "Don't pay the ferryman until he gets you to the other side" ([Chris de Burgh, 1982](https://youtu.be/lqZEp4Fb6qw)) and how it might be rendered in Latin.

How about:

> Ne prius portitorem solvas quam ad alteram ripam te transtulerit.

i.e., literally, "before he will have brought you." Am I right to use the future perfect after *prius quam*? Usually, if the main clause is in the present tense, we would expect a perfect in the subordinate clause; the future perfect would be expected for a future main clause. My reasoning is that *ne solvas* is essentially a sort of imperative, and imperatives have future character. Is that plausible?

Comment: Should _portitorem_ be _portitori_?

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: It could be argued that paying the ferryman is a future event; he hasn't been paid yet. The payment should only take place when the boat arrives--simultaneous events. Alternatively, a conditional sentence: "Not until the boat arrives, will  I pay." This requiring a  future perfect (advenerit) and a future (solvam), these preceded by "non priusquam", I think.

Comment: @BenKovitz that would certainly not be wrong, but Georges also suggests *aliquem solvere* (and he's not talking about slaves).